# Shift arrow selection in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm using GNU Emacs 23.2.1
my init.el

```
(cua-mode 1)               
(transient-mark-mode 1)    
(setq shift-select-mode t) 
(global-linum-mode 1)      
(show-paren-mode 1)        
(desktop-save-mode 1)
```

So, instead of selection I get 2C on Shift =>, 2D on Shift <=, etc.
How to solve this?

P.S.
cat -v for Shift <=
^[[1;2D
cat -v for Shift =>
^[[1;2C

How I can map properly those keys to shift-left, shift-right corresponding?

P.P.S.
Sorry. I've forgot. I'm also using screen.

```
den@playground:~/.emacs.den$ echo $TERM  
screen
```

Solution:

```
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2D" [S-left])  
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2C" [S-right])  
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2B" [S-down])  
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2A" [S-up])  
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2F" [S-end])  
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2H" [S-home])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means emacs and your terminal do not agree on what the various key codes mean.  there are more advanced ways to configure terminals (terminal specific files), but to get you started, try adding something like this to your emacs init file:

```
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2D" [S-left])
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2C" [S-right])
```

Comment: In my `screen` the unshifted arrow keys send the same keycodes as the shifted ones. You want to make sure this is not the case for you before you embark on something like this.

Comment: @tripleee - yep, there's all kinds of things you need to consider (the terminal, your shell, etc), which is what makes it so frustrating.  sometimes the terminal or shell will let you change the keycodes, which can help in that situation.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when you run emacs in a console. Try running emacs as a graphical program and this should not be an issue.

Comment: yes, I'm running it on my server via ssh/mintty. Sorry - I could not use X server. Only ssh.

Comment: Then I think you cannot use these key combinations. IIRC these keys will not be passed to emacs but will be stopped by the terminal that does not have enough character codes to send them. What you can do is remap to something else, or do X forwarding through SSH, or use tramp to run a local version of emacs and edit files remotely.