# emacs shift arrow selection selects only 1st char/line

Tags: emacs, elisp

This question is linked to my previous one: [Shift arrow selection in emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11721224/658346)
It was solved but partially only.
For now I have another problem:
when I'm pressing shift-right 2 times - only last selection will be present. So. It is not extended (as it should be according my achivements) but always overwritten...

f.e. I have 1 word "window" only. And my cursor at position 0. I want to copy "wi" only. I've pressed shift-right 2 times. But only "i" was selected.
How I can fix this?

```
den@playground:~/.emacs.den$ cat -v
^[[1;2C^[[1;2C

M-x version
GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (i486-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.20.0) of 2010-12-11 on raven, modified by Debian
```

I'm running my emacs on a remote machine via screen

```
den@playground:~/.emacs.den$ echo $TERM
screen
```

Without screen

```
den@playground:~$ echo $TERM
xterm
```

Behavior the same as under screen.

As I have understood the problem. Emacs after each shift-right click overwrites selection instead of expanding it...

So. Without screen and without my scripts (emacs -q).
Shift-right, shift-left, shift-down - working. shift-up - doing nothing. So. cursor is not moved after shift-up is pressed.  Also shift-home, shift-end are working. shift-pgdown, shift-pgup - does not.

With screen and without my scripts (emacs -q).
Nothing.

Comment: If you do `cat -v` on the remote machine and type [Shift-arrow] twice, do you get the expected control sequence twice?

Comment: could you give a bit more information about your emacs version and environment?  when i tried this, "wi" is properly selected.  i am using emacs 23.3 (9.0) on MacOS X 10.7.4 .

Comment: I tried in a debian x86_64 with the same version of emacs without screen and I did not need to do the rebinding for it to work perfectly. Did you try with `emacs -q` without screen to make sure your configuration was not creating the problem.

Comment: Tested again under `tmux` instead of `screen`. I needed the input-decode-map bit but the 1 character problem did not arise.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you press Shift-right 2 times, and not press on 'w' <kbd>C-SPACE</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd>

This selects the `wi`. Now you press <kbd>M-w</kbd>, and you copied it.

Probably I understood wrong the problem ?

Comment: what denys is asking is a valid question.  your key-sequence will also work, but in recent versions of emacs, what he wants to do should work correctly.