# shift-end not working in emacs terminal mode

Tags: emacs, gnome-terminal

I have set up my emacs so that I can highlight regions with shift + arrows, PgUp, PgDown, Home and End keys, and in window mode that works fine. In terminal mode the combinations Shift+End and Shift+Home do nothing. All other combinations work. Has anyone else encountered this and knows how to fix it? I'm using Gnome Terminal 3.6.2 and emacs 23.3.1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shift arrow selection in emacs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721224/shift-arrow-selection-in-emacs)

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate. Shift selection with arrow keys works fine. It's just the Shift+End and Shift+Home which isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "set up my emacs so that I can highlight regions with shift + arrows" since AFAIK this is the default behavior, but if they do nothing I think it's because these key combinations are somehow caught by your window-manager.
At least here on Debian, with gnome-terminal 3.12.2 they work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Gnome-terminal (actually the underlying vte widget) has recently received many emulation fixes, including fixing the keys with modifiers. Upgrading to a recent version will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04 with gnome-terminal.

This is a problem with gnome-terminal.  If I use XTerm, then it works as expected.  There is a similar problem with Ctrl-Home and Ctrl-End.  Those keys send the same key code as Home and End.